# rich:pickList not working as expected when using "display:none" (richfaces 3.3.3)

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, picklist

I am using RichFaces 3.3.3 with jsf 1.2 and I have discovered that if I have a rich:pickList within a div with `style="display:none"` and show it only when some conditions are fulfilled it is not working correctly. It disables the '`copy`' & '`remove`' button and only the '`copy all`' and '`remove all`' buttons work.

Has anybody seen this case?